# CSS Pseudo elements positioning issue

Tags: html, css

I am facing an issue with positioning and alignment of pseudo elements. I have pasted the snippet below. Could you please tell me why the elements are overlapping and how to get them to appear next to each other without the overlap?

```css
.switch {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.switch label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  height: 18px;
  width: 33px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background-color: gray;
  top: 2px;
  right: -50px;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  right: -50px;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"] + label::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  top: 4px;
  right: -33px;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  right: -48px;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
  <label for="checkbox1">Lorem ipsum Test</label>
</div>
<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
  <label for="checkbox2">Test1</label>
</div>
<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
  <label for="checkbox3">Lorem ipsum Test2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: is that what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/rws7er0u/

Comment: thanks for your response. i want them to appear in one line without overlap. right now the toggle switch is overlapping the text label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They overlap because [`position: absolute`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolute-positioning) takes elements out of the normal flow:

> In the absolute positioning model, a box is explicitly offset with
>   respect to its containing block. It is removed from the normal flow
>   entirely (it has no impact on later siblings). [...] the contents of
>   an absolutely positioned element do not flow around any other boxes.
>   They may obscure the contents of another box (or be obscured
>   themselves)

You can add some margin to fix that:

```css
.switch label {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```css
.switch {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.switch label {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 50px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.switch input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  height: 18px;
  width: 33px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background-color: gray;
  top: 2px;
  right: -50px;
}
.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  right: -50px;
}
.switch input[type="checkbox"] + label::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  top: 4px;
  right: -33px;
}
.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  right: -48px;
}
.switch input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
  <label for="checkbox1">Lorem ipsum Test</label>
</div>
<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
  <label for="checkbox2">Test1</label>
</div>
<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
  <label for="checkbox3">Lorem ipsum Test2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Oriol. This works fine! will accept your answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 2):

When an element is absolutely positioned it gets out of the normal flow. This means that it does not affect other elements with its dimensions/positioning.

A solution is to take into consideration its dimensions/positioning in the container element (*the `label` in this case*)

So giving a `padding-right:50px` to the `label` and positioning the pseudo-elements accordingly will fix it.

**Updated code**

```css
.switch {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.switch label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right:50px;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  height: 18px;
  width: 33px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background-color: gray;
  top: 2px;
  right: 0;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  right: 0;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"] + label::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  top: 4px;
  right: 17px;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  right: 2px;
}

.switch input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
  <label for="checkbox1">Lorem ipsum Test</label>
</div>
<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
  <label for="checkbox2">Test1</label>
</div>
<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
  <label for="checkbox3">Lorem ipsum Test2</label>
</div>
```